# $.ajax not working when used in ("click") event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

This is my Javascript code:

```
const checkbox = document.querySelector("#checkbox");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var text = "";
    if(checkbox.checked === true){
        text = "Is Checked";
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/update_if_checked/',
        data: {'is_checked': text},
        type: 'POST'
     }).done(function(response){
       console.log(response);
     });

});
```

I am getting an error which says $.ajax is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.

Here, checkbox is an input of type checkbox and when the button whose id is "button" is clicked, I want to send the data i.e. if the checkbox is checked to the Django Server.

I have imported this version of jquery in HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
```

EDIT

Sorry about the id of the button that's button only.

HTML:

```
<div>Check<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></div>
<button id="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well please. Not working is not really helpful with that much information

Comment: `not a function` is normally because the script hasn't been included at the time you run it - as it's in an event handler that's unlikely (assuming it *is* included) - `$.ajax not a function` is normally because you've included `.slim` version (you confirm this is not the case) - so it could be that you've included jquery-3.1.1 manually, but your *framework* has also included a version of jquery after this (normally at the bottom) (and likely the .slim version) - you might think "no that can't be" but it happens *a lot* with frameworks and questions on SO.  Check the **rendered** output.

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the jQuery scripts in the `head`  of the page ?

Comment: Add this `button.addEventListener("click", function(e){ console.log($) });` and provide us the ouput.

Comment: Add this jQuery script instead of the current one `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah I will try that

Comment: @AlwaysHelping _"Add this..."_ - Why?

Comment: @Andreas Guessing JQuery script load issue. Trying some options here.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I've tried that too but it doesn't work

Comment: @Saat Something else does not seems right then. what did you get when you `console.log($)` in the click function ?

Comment: @Saat why is your button `id` and checkbox `id` is same ? Is not that suppose to be `#button` as per the JS you have ?

Comment: Looks like a jquery mismatch, but no response from OP as to what *actual* version of jquery is running (regardless of what has been entered in the source).

Answer (score 0):

Your html elements has two similar ids

```
<div>Check<input type="checkbox" id="**checkbox**"></div>
<button id="**checkbox**">Submit</button>
```

Change one to checkboxinput and the other to checkboxbutton

Comment: This seems to be a typo in the question. Otherwise the click handler (with the `$.ajax()` call) wouldn't be executed and the error message wouldn't mention a `HTMLButtonElement`

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybie:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     //Try to add your event listener here
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO - in this case the question indicates the `$.ajax` is being hit, so it's not a case that the js is running before the DOM element exists.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using your code works fine. Make sure to include jQuery BEFORE your regular JS code. Tried in JSFiddle and do not get any $.ajax() errors besides CORS, of course, because we do not have access to the path (URL for AJAX call).

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector("#checkbox");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var text = "";
    if(checkbox.checked === true){
        text = "Is Checked";
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/update_if_checked/',
        data: {'is_checked': text},
        type: 'POST'
     }).done(function(response){
       console.log(response);
     });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Check<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></div>
<button id="button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your html code, both of the elements i.e. the checkbox and the button have same id. Make it different.

```
<div>Check<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"></div>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

The script part, I have written it using jquery.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#button").click(function(){
        var text = "";
        if($("#checkbox").is(":checked")){
            text = "Is Checked";
        }
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/update_if_checked/',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify({"is_checked": text}),
          success: function(response){
             console.log(response);
          },
          error: function(error){
             console.log(error);
          }
        }).done(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO - in this case the question indicates the `$.ajax` is being hit, so it's not a case that the button/checkbox IDs are breaking the event.